# Understanding why I am wrong at calculating N points on the same semicircle

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

I have read the solutions to the popular problem: with n points uniformly distributed on the circle, what is the probability that that they lie on the same semicircle? The general approach is to define $E_i$ the event that all points lie on the same semicircle and the semi-circle is started at point i. Then because these events are disjoint, you have that $$P(semicircle) = \sum P(E_i) = n/2^{n-1}$$

I am approaching this question from another angle but getting it wrong
$$P(semicircle) = \sum P(semicircle | semicircle \ started \ at \ P_i) P(semicircle \ started \ at \ P_i)$$

This yields $$n * 1/2^{n-1} 1/n$$ which is clearly wrong. What do I need to do here to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your answer is the probability that the points all lie in the (clockwise) semicircle starting at one of the points chosen at random, but you want the probability that the points all lie in any of the $n$ (clockwise) semicircles starting at each of the points.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean  by the first factor ?

$$P(semicircle | semicircle \ started \ at \ P_i)$$

I cannot make sense of it. If the conditioning event is "the points form a semicircle starting at $P_i$"... then the probability of the other event is $1$.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Why is the probability of the other event 1?

Comment: To clarify, I see this as  P(semicircle | the semicircle is started at $P_i$)P(the semicircle is started at $P_i$) where P(the semicircle is started at $P_i$) should be 1/n. This is because the semicircle must start at 1 position and all points are equally likely, so prob is 1/n

Comment: " Why is the probability of the other event 1?"
Because you already know (give as condition) that the points form a semicircle.

Comment: The event "the semicircle is started at $P_i$" comprises two things : 1. "the points form a semicircle" AND "that semicircle starts at $P_i$"